# Insert external link to swf (using a wysiwyg editor)

Tags: actionscript-3, joomla, flash

I have developed a website for a friend, which has to include some swf files. Those files come from his customers who want to get advertised at his site, and therefore cannot be edited.

The site is made with the use of Joomla 2.5.

My problem is that some of the swf files, do not have the target URL as part of them, and I'm trying to add it using the WYSIWYG editor that Joomla administrator panel provides.

I have tried various things reading different opinions in forums, but nothing works.

And another weird thing, is that when I click one of those, it takes me to a blank page, with the url "http://www.mysite.com/_level0.clickTAG" (where http://www.mysite.com is the name of my friend's site)

Is there a way of inserting a link externally to a swf file, or this is something that cannot be done?

Thank you in advance for your time.

Edit 1:

I have modified my html into

```
<p><object width="300" height="240" data="images/BANNERS_2014/bannername.swf?clickTAG=http:/www.customersite.com" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"><param name="src" value="images/BANNERS_2014/bannername.swf?clickTAG=http:/www.customersite.gr" /></object></p>
```

and now then I click on the banner, it takes me to `http://www.mysite.com/www.customersite.com`

instead of `http://www.customersite.com`

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the clickTAG as a parameter when you are embedding your SWF. I would have two fields on Joomla. One for the SWF and one for the destination URL. Then you can compose your embed code combining both. Read the article below and pay close attention to the bottom of the page:

http://www.adobe.com/resources/richmedia/tracking/designers_guide/

You can also have a similar set up as the one I outlined above and overlay a div on top of your SWF with the click event on it and the destination URL. You should have more control that way in the event that the SWFs you are getting are not formatted correctly.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I have just made some more tests, and I have edited my question with the status that I'm in right now. Can you please tell me what do you think I should change in order for it to work?

Comment: You should accept the answer and create a new question, that helps keep question/answers clean. Otherwise we can go forever on the topic or have multiple q&a post. To answer your question, your clickTAG is malformed that is why the destination URL is not working.

Comment: by saying that my clickTag is malformed, you mean that they have given me a malformed swf, or the way I'm using it is wrong?

Comment: The way you have it on your sample or your EDIT area.